# WPF MVVM Button Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, button, mvvm

My job is to create a button in wpf (using mvvm), that contains an animation (preferably with sound). If clicking on the button, the lock-to-unlock animation (and the EnableControlsCommandVVM for enabling some textbox-controls) should start, play the lock-to-unlock-sound and stop by showing the last animations' image. 
If clicking a second time on the button, the unlock-to-lock animation (and the EnableControlsCommandVVM now for disabling some textbox-controls) should start, play the unlock-to-lock-sound and stop by showing the last animations' image, and so on...
I already have 16 different Lock-State*.png-files as well as an Lock.mp4-file (that shows the animation of the 16 different Lock-State*.png-files in a short film surrounded by sound) and a Lock.gif-animation file (that also shows the animation of the 16 different Lock-State*.png-files (but without sound)).

**Here is the code of my not-animated button**

```
<Button Name="LockUnlockBtn" Height="25" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
    Visibility="{Binding IsLockUnlockBtnVisibleVVM, Converter={StaticResource IsControlVisible}, FallbackValue=Hidden}"
    Command="{Binding EnableControlsCommandVVM}">
    <Image>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\Locked-Icon.png" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLockedVVM}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\Unlocked-Icon.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: Can you please include the code or Xaml where the animation was declared?

Comment: Well there isn't any code for any animation-function.

Comment: Many users on the site (including me) have a general expectation that you would have attempted to craft one or more of your animations so that we could see what you have tried so far and that your overall approach was sound.  I wouldn't be optimistic that you would get a good answer based upon what you have provided so far.  For the sound part, wiring up sounds to events is quite straight-forward and has sufficient scope for a good answer though.